# Set property of enum type given by string

Tags: c#, properties, enums

I got some enum's in my class, it's look like this one:

```
public enum A { A1, A2 }
public enum B { B1, B2 }
```

Problem is when i try to read items from XML file (each field given by property name and property value - both string).

Now i got my method which is setting value of single property (there is only part with isEnum check).

```
public A classfield
{
  get;
  set;
}
public bool DynamicallySetItemProperty(string name, string value)
{
  // value = "A1" or "A2"; - value given in string.
  // name = "classfield"; - name of property.
  PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty(name);
  if (p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
  {
    var a = (A) Enum.Parse(typeof(A), value);
    p.SetValue(this, a);
  }
  return true;
}
```

But in this one i'm not checking if field is A or B-enum.

Is there any way to make my method checking type of enum and then parsing my string to this enum, something like this one:

```
public bool DynamicallySetItemProperty(string name,string value)
{
  PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty(name);
  if (p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
  {    
    var a = (p.GetType()) Enum.Parse(typeof(p.GetType()), value); // <- it doesn't work
    p.SetValue(this, a);
  }
  return true;
}
```

So i need to check property for its enum-type and then parse my string value to this enum-type without using  if/else or switch statement (it's problematic when i got a lot of enum types). Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: var a = Enum.Parse(p.GetType(), value);

Comment: How xml-file looks like? Can't you determine exact type (e.g. tag `<A>`)? Some serializers (e.g. json.net) are storing `Type` explicitly, otherwise there is no way to distinct `A` from `B`, you may have to do the same. If you can determine at least `Enum` type, then you can enumerate all enums and check which value it could be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to further check the type. `Enum.Parse()` takes the type as first parameter, and the type you need is `p.PropertyType` (as this is the *type of the property*. `SetValue()` takes an `object` as parameter for the value anyway, so there is no need to cast the return value of `Enum.Parse()`:

```
PropertyInfo p = this.GetType().GetProperty(name);
if (p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
   p.SetValue(this, Enum.Parse(p.PropertyType, value));
```

---

**Note** that `p.GetType()` returns the `Type` instance for `PropertyInfo`, not the enum type!

Comment: Look at op statement: *"each field given by property name and property value - both string"* - how did you get a type? How do you know it's enum?

Comment: @Sinatr you get a `PropertyInfo` for the property to set like the OP via `this.GetType().GetProperty(name)`. This `PropertyInfo` has a property `PropertyType` which _is the type of the property_. `Enum.Parse()` expects exactly that type instance as first parameter. It's not a generic method, it does not need a type literal, but an instance of `Type` representing the type.

Comment: @Sinatr And I know it's an enum because `p.IsEnum` is true.

Comment: Thanks. Last comment is overkill ;)

Comment: I knew the difference between `.GetType()`  and `.PropertyType`, but i mixed them with each other here, my fault... Now it's working fine with your solution, thanks :d

Answer (score 0):

You won´t need this, because  `PropertyInfo.SetValue` expects an instance of `object` as second parameter. So you won´t need to take care on the specific type and simply can use this:

```
var parsedValue = Enum.Parse(p.PropertyType, value);
p.SetValue(this, parsedValue, null);
```